# Delegate function not calling

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, delegates, protocols

I have 2 `UIViewControllers`, `ViewController`, `SecondViewController`. I defined delegate function in VC, and using in Second VC. But delegate functions not calling in Second VC.

This is mu **first VC** code

```
import UIKit

//Step1:
protocol testDelegate {
    func testFunction(string1: String, string2:String)
    func math(a:Int, b:Int)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Step2:
    var delegateVariable: testDelegate?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func moveToSecondVC(_ sender: Any) {
    let nav = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC") as! SecondViewController
    //Step3:
    delegateVariable?.testFunction(string1: "String1", string2: "String2")
    delegateVariable?.math(a:30, b:10)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)
}

}
```

My **second VC** code

```
import UIKit

//Step4:
class SecondViewController: UIViewController , testDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Step5:
    let svc = ViewController()
    svc.delegateVariable = self
}

@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
    //Step5:
    let svc = ViewController()
    svc.delegateVariable = self
}

//Step6:
func testFunction(string1: String, string2: String) {
    print(string1+string2)
}
func math(a:Int, b:Int) {
    print(a+b)
    print(a-b)
    print(a*b)
}
}
```

Here i'm just passing small amount of data for practice, but can any one please suggest some high level delegate example tutorial links for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is why nothing is happening...

```
let svc = ViewController()
svc.delegateVariable = self
```

You are creating a NEW ViewController, not using the one that is actually in use.

It does not look like you are using the delegate pattern properly. Your ViewController should not be calling code on other view controllers.

SecondViewController should "do stuff" and then let ViewController know what it has done.

For the Math function you could just use a new class (not a view controller) and create and use this as needed. You do not need a ViewController for this.

An example of using a delegate might be something like:

```
protocol CreateProfileDelegate: class {
   func didCreateProfile(profile: Profile?)
   func didCancelCreateProfile()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func showCreateProfile() {
       let vc = CreateProfileViewController() 
       vc.delegate = self
       present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: CreateProfileDelegate {

    func didCreateProfile(profile: Profile?) {
       // show the profile?
    }

    func didCancelCreateProfile() {
        // show an alert maybe? 
    }
}
```

This way the SecondViewController (CreateProfileViewController) basically tells the first that something has happened so that it can react to it.

Comment: I'm not understood your answer, can you please suggest with my code

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't make much sense. They are not real world examples (testFunction, math) What you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Scriptable... What is the need to delegate to pass data from vc1 -> vc2 . Don't just he use navigation?

Comment: @wings thats what I said in my answer? there is no need to pass from vc1 -> vc2

Comment: @ Scriptable, actually I'm trying to learn delegates, that's why I'm asking some good real world example tutorial link in last.

Comment: @ Scriptable, can you [please suggest any good tutorial link for me to learn delegates in real time...

Comment: asking for links, tutorials, sdk's/libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow. check the raywenderlich site or do some googling, there are lots of resources available

Answer (score 1):

in SecondViewController you are setting....

```
let svc = ViewController()
svc.delegateVariable = self
```

That just create an object of `ViewController()` class and then you set the delegate. So when the obj. of the scope is finished then the memory of the object will be increased automatically.

The flow should like below....

**Create an object of the Viewcontroller in SecondViewController and set the delegate**

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
vc.delegateVariable = self
```

**Then push the view controller in to the navigation stack.**

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
```

**Implement the delegate method of `testDelegate` in SecondViewController**

```
 func testFunction(string1: String, string2: String) {
   print(string1+string2)
 } 

func math(a:Int, b:Int) {

}
```

**EDIT**

The final code of the SecondViewController Will be...

```
import UIKit


class SecondViewController: UIViewController , testDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()


 }

@IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
  vc.delegateVariable = self 
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
}

//MARK:- TestDelegate Methods
 func testFunction(string1: String, string2: String) {
   print(string1+string2)
 }

  func math(a:Int, b:Int) {
    print(a+b)
    print(a-b)
    print(a*b)
  }
}
```

Comment: class SecondViewController: UIViewController , testDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        //Step5:
        let svc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC") as! ViewController
        svc.delegateVariable = self
    }  it's not calling

Comment: for 1st time it's not calling

Comment: And I'm trying to pass data from vc1 to vc2, that's why I wrote this code in vc1 protocol testDelegate {
    func testFunction(string1: String, string2:String)
    func math(a:Int, b:Int)
}

Comment: From this code you need to pass data from vc2 to vc1, then delegate will work

Comment: @ Mahendra GP, If I want to pass data from VC1 to VC2 , what I need to do?. VC2 to VC2 case working for me, but VC1 to VC2 to pass data what we need to do?

Comment: You can just create a variable in VC2 and when you are moving from VC1 to VC2 then just assign the value to the VC2's variable. No need to user delegate in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192716/discussion-between-ios-and-mahendra-gp).